# Force element to hide on click outside of textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#H-Alert').hide();

$('html').click(function (e) {
    if (e.target.className == '.h-textbox') {
        $('#H-Alert').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#H-Alert').hide();
    }
});
});
```

I have referenced this:

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect a click outside an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for the [blur](https://api.jquery.com/blur/) and [focus](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) events. You can do this using jQuery as follows:

```
$('#H-Alert').hide();
$(window).ready(function(){
    $('.h-textbox').blur(function(){
      $('#H-Alert').show();
    }).focus(function(){
      $('#H-Alert').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you. that worked. I just changed a few things. `$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Hobbs-Alert').hide();
    $('.hobbs-textbox').blur(function () {
        $('#Hobbs-Alert').hide();
    }).focus(function () {
        $('#Hobbs-Alert').show();
    });
});
`

Answer (score 1):

For events on entering or leaving textboxes the solution of @meltuhamy may be better, but if you like to work with the events directly, you could use this:

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    if($(event.target).closest(".h-textbox").length == 0) {
        if($("#H-Alert").is(":visible")) {
            $("#H-Alert").hide();
        } else {
            $("#H-Alert").show();
        }
    }
});
```